# Install a pure C binary when installing a Perl module

Tags: perl

I have a part of my Perl module written in C. The module uses the C pthreads library. I was first thinking to add the C code to my module using a standard XS wrapper but this seems possible only in Perl 5.22 because of this bug report: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122906

My C code doesn't really require any interaction with the rest of Perl code. It just reads a file and writes to another file.

In order to not limit my module to Perl 5.22 and up I was thinking about compiling a simple C binary and calling it from my Perl code using `system`or backticks.

So my question is: Is it possible to add this kind of target to Makefile.PL and if yes how?
And maybe an input on if this kind of installation process is desirable for a Perl module as I might also just release the C code separately on Github.
To me it seems logical to install it alongside the Perl module as the C binary has no other use than to work with the Perl module.

Comment: I think you're better off asking this in #toolchain on irc.perl.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever you want to the generated `Makefile` by adding a function to your `Makefile.PL` named `MY::postamble()` that simply returns the string you want added. This is documented in the `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` manpage, if you want to read more.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I did add the MY::postamble() piece of makefile from ExtUtils::MakeMaker docs and a EXE_FILES => [ qw(c_module/c_module_binary) ] to the Makefile.PL to have it copied to the system default binary folder by "make install".